# How can I decode a hexadecimal to a byte array in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter, hex

So there's the `'dart:convert'` library, which contains a HexDecoder class that doesn't seem to have a constructor (according to [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/convert/latest/convert/HexDecoder-class.html)). But importing it and trying to construct it doesn't work; I thought maybe there was a default constructor not mentioned.

I could copy the code in the source for the convert method, but I'd rather make this a learning opportunity. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`HexDecoder` isn't actually in `dart:convert`. It's in a package (also) called `convert`.

You need to add it to your `pubspec.yaml` and then use an import like:

```
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';
```

Then use it like this:

```
  hex.decode('abcdef');
```

`hex` is a const singleton instance of the codec. (The constructor is private; you don't need to instantiate your own - use the existing const instance.)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants to convert hexadecimal numbers to 2's component, Dart has a builtin method .toSigned(int):

```
var testConversion = 0xC1.toSigned(8);
print("This is the result: " + testConversion.toString()); // prints -63
```